# Posicionamento de mensagems

Tags: php

Tenho uma tela de login e gostaria de saber como posicionar por exemplo a mensagem de "senha inválida" após uma consulta malsucedida (em PDO), dentro do campo form (html) de login ou abaixo do campo senha por exemplo.

1 - Campo Login (html) <--(posicionar mensagem retorno "senha inválida") (OPC1)
2 - Campo Senha (html) 
3- (posicionar mensagem retorno "senha inválida") (OPC2)